# Rails: access resource model from ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, applicationcontroller

So, I've the following method in the ApplicationController, which is need to be accessed by all controllers:

```
  def alter_some_attribute
    @recurso = resource.find(params[:id])

    ...
  end
```

This method only alters a common attribute that all models have. I've tested and the controllers access pretty good to the method. The question is how do I get the models name of the resource who access the method?

I've tried `resource`, `resource_model`, `resource[:model]` and all of them return the error: `undefined method 'resource' for #<SomeController:0xb64a1418>`

Comment: Please write some example of how you going to call this method in models

Comment: Does `resource.class.model_name` help?

Comment: I'm not calling it from a model. I'll call it from a view. It will update a common param that all model have (sort of an active or inactive state).

Comment: It returns `undefined method 'resource' for #<SomeController:0xb64a1418>`

Comment: Well, you'd have to access it as @recurso, since `resource` isn't actually defined as a method on the controller.  I have to admit, I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If if rightly understand you, you can try:

```
resourse.class
```

Comment: It returns `undefined method 'resource' for #<SomeController:0xb64a1418>`